# Excel VBA- Need to compare two tables in the same sheet. the input tables will be given as selection using mouse

Tags: vba, excel

I want to compare two tables in the same sheet. I will select the first table and click on button to give as first input. Similarly I will give next table input. When I click 'compare' button, the result should be displayed by highlighting cells in the second table. Please help me to do this.

Below is the script I Used to compare two tables in two sheets. Please help me to find to give input using selection option

```
Private Sub CompareBtn_Click()
Dim first_index As Integer
Dim last_index As Integer
Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim r1 As Integer
Dim r2 As Integer
Dim found As Boolean
Dim rng As Range

    Set sheet1 = Worksheets("Source")
    Set sheet2 = Worksheets("Minus")


    first_index = 1
    last_index = sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count



    For r2 = first_index To last_index
        found = False

        For r1 = first_index To last_index
            If sheet1.Cells(r1, 1) = sheet2.Cells(r2, 1) _
                And _
               sheet1.Cells(r1, 2) = sheet2.Cells(r2, 2) _
            Then

                found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next r1


        If Not found Then

            sheet2.Cells(r2, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
            sheet2.Cells(r2, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
        End If
    Next r2
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not a script writing service. What have you tried yourself?

Comment: @CallumDA33- I have added the code I used

Comment: Why don't you just use conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Sub CompareTable()

    Dim oldTable As Range, newTable As Range, i As Integer, J As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    Set oldTable = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Raw Data", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
    Set newTable = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Processed Data", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)

    i = oldTable.Rows.Count
    J = oldTable.Columns.Count

    For m = 1 To i
        For n = 1 To J
            If oldTable.Cells(m, n) <> newTable.Cells(m, n) Then
                newTable.Cells(m, n).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        Next n
    Next m

End Sub
```

This will ask you for two ranges. Select the two tables that you want to compare and the differences will be highlighted in the second table.

**EDIT**:
**_________________________________________________________________________________**

Or you can update your code to:

```
Sub CompareBtn_Click()
    Dim first_index As Integer
    Dim last_index As Integer
    Dim rows_index As Integer, columns_index As Integer
    Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim sheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim r1 As Integer
    Dim r2 As Integer
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim rng As Range

    Set sheet1 = Worksheets("Source")
    Set sheet2 = Worksheets("Minus")

    rows_index = sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    columns_index = sheet2.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For r2 = 1 To rows_index
        For r1 = 1 To columns_index
            If sheet1.Cells(r2, r1) <> sheet2.Cells(r2, r1) Then
                sheet2.Cells(r2, r1).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
            End If
        Next r1
    Next r2
    sheet2.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I am a beginner in macro. You have helped a lot

Comment: @BenThomas - Glad I could help.